# Resetting Python list contents in nested loop

Tags: python, list, loops, reset

I have some files in this format that I need to return the oldest and newest files to pass to a function for parsing

```
Nv_NODE_DATE_TIME
```

I would like the output to be

```
Nv_stats_172550_160211_230030
Nv_stats_172550_160212_142624
Nv_stats_75AKPD0_160211_230030
Nv_stats_75AKPD0_160212_142624
```

but I am getting the absolute first item and absolute last item

```
Nv_stats_172550_160211_230030
Nv_stats_75AKPD0_160212_142624
Nv_stats_172550_160211_230030
Nv_stats_75AKPD0_160212_142624
```

Here is the current code

```
import os

iostatslocalpath="/root/svc/testing/"
svchost='SVC_Cluster01'
nodenames=['75AKMX0', '75AKPD0', '172550', '172561']

filelist=sorted(os.listdir(iostatslocalpath+svchost+'/.'))
totalfilenumber=len(filelist)

def parse(filename, length):
        print filename[0]
        print test[length-1]

for nodename in nodenames:
        test=[]
        test[:]=[]
        for file in filelist:
                if nodename and "Nv" in file:
                        test.append(file)
        parse(test, len(test))
```

There is probably something small I am overlooking, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where are you telling it to sort by the datetime?

Comment: I added a possible error in the parse function as well as pointing to the error in the if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the

```
def parse(filename, length):
    print filename[0]
    print test[length-1]
```

uses test. You should probably make it

```
def parse(filename, length):
    print filename[0]
    print filename[length-1]
```

Then

```
if nodename and "Nv" in file:
```

does the in first and then does the and. [5.15. Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) It thus is the equivalent of

```
if (nodename) and ("NV" in file):
```

Since you are looping over nodename the first section is alway true.

You probably want to use

```
if (nodename in file) and ("Nv" in file):
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides what sabbahillel said, `test` returns the correct listing, however this `parse` function looks weird, since you ask it to print the first item in the list, then the last, so it won't print all the files as you wish. The following code will print it correctly, although I believe your `parse` function is the root of your confusion:

```
import os

iostatslocalpath="/root/svc/testing/"
svchost='SVC_Cluster01'
nodenames=sorted(['75AKMX0', '75AKPD0', '172550', '172561'])

filelist=sorted(os.listdir(iostatslocalpath+svchost+'/.'))
# print filelist
totalfilenumber=len(filelist)

def parse(filename, length):
        print filename[0]
        print test[length-1]

for nodename in nodenames:
        test=[]
        test[:]=[]
        for file in filelist:
                if nodename in file and "Nv" in file:
                        test.append(file)
        for x in test:
            print(x)
```

Outputs:

```
Nv_stats_172550_160211_230030
Nv_stats_172550_160212_142624
Nv_stats_75AKPD0_160211_230030
Nv_stats_75AKPD0_160212_142624
```

So x are the files in the order you wish, then you parse them as you wish.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out I should have been using print filename[length-1] instead of print test[length-1] along with the modified and statement

Comment: Also this would only work for lists of len 2, since you're not printing every element, but only first and last. And `filename[length-1]` is not necessary, `filename[-1]` works fine in python. Lastly, could you accept my answer?